# Int to BigInteger, what's the difference?

Tags: java, math, biginteger

I transfer the modExp function from int to BigInteger, but the result is different, what the different of these two functions?

Thanks!!!

The function with BigInteger, the result always 1:

```
public static BigInteger modExp(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");       
    if (b == BigInteger.ZERO)
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger t = modExp (a, b.divide(two), n);
    BigInteger c = (t.pow(2)).mod(n);
    if (b.mod(two) == BigInteger.ONE)
        c = (c.multiply(a)).mod(n);
    return c;       
}
```

The function with int:

```
public static int modexp(int a, int b, int n) {
    if (b == 0) return 1;
    long t = modexp(a, b/2, n);  // use long for intermediate computations to eliminate overflow
    long c = (t * t) % n;
    if (b % 2 == 1)
       c = (c * a) % n;
    return (int) c;
}
```

The function is to calculate `a^b mod p`, For example:

```
a=4 b=6 p=11  result1 = 1  result2 = 4
a=9 b=2 p=11  result1 = 1  result2 = 4
a=5 b=6 p=23  result1 = 1  result2 = 8 ...
```

Comment: What is the difference in the results?  At what point in the computations do they diverge?

Comment: Is it returning 1 because of the b==0 if statement?

Comment: Use `compareTo` instead of `==`.

Comment: do you have a debugging tool like Xdebug?

Comment: I have tested `b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0` but the result is same, so I use `==` to make it simple

Comment: Instead of integer division by 2, use `.shiftRight(1)` (but mind negative numbers), and test on zero might be done with `.signum() == 0`.

Comment: Oh, I forget change `==1`, when I change it, it is correct. Thanks

Comment: `==` is definitely not correct, it's object equality. It works sometimes when comparing constants like ZERO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obvious difference is the difference between `int` and `BigInteger`.

One difference is that `int` is a primitive type and `BigInteger` is a reference type. As such, it is better to use equals() when comparing `BigInteger`s. So `b == BigInteger.ZERO` should be `BigInteger.ZERO.equals(b)`.

BigInteger is more suited to working with big numbers and will prevent you running into problems with overflowing the max `int` value, supported by Java.

Overflowing may be the cause you are getting a different result from the two functions as well. When this occurs, it doesn't cause any exception to be thrown, but the values of the `int`s get messed up.

Comment: I used it but it still wrong. I also try `b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0` but the result is still 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I need change both `b == BigInteger.ZERO` and `b.mod(two) == BigInteger.ONE` to compareTo, the result is correct, thanks!

Comment: Did you change this `b.mod(two) == BigInteger.ONE` comparison also? I suggest you debug both methods step by step and trace how the result changes. It's the easiest way to find the errors

Answer (score 0):

In java int can count from -2^31 up to 2^31-1 because int are coded over 4 bytes but long can count from -2^63 up to 2^63-1 because long are coded over 8 bytes.

In the second method with this :

```
return (int) c;
```

you may loose data (the 4 first byte)

That could explain why your result are different because BigInteger are coded over much more byte than long